# Get the value of a custom checkout field in woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

In Woocommerce checkout, I am adding a custom checkout field and here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'shipping_add_select_checkout_field' );
function shipping_add_select_checkout_field( WC_Checkout $checkout ) {
    $options = array_merge( [ '' => __( 'Nothing to select' ), ], city_zone() );
    woocommerce_form_field( 'billing_country_zone', array(
            'type'     => 'select',
            'class'    => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
            'label'    => __( 'City zone' ),
            'required' => true,
            'options'  => $options
    ), WC()->customer->billing_country_zone );
}
```

Now I am totally lost as I need to know what is `WC()->customer->billing_country_zone` for and how can I check it's value…

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the`WC()->customer->billing_country_zone`:

- First since Woocommerce 3, properties can be accessed on most all Woocommerce instances objects.
- And "`billing_country_zone`" is no a default property of `WC_Customer` instance object.

As it's **about checkout fields**, instead you should use `$checkout` argument which is the instance of the `WC_Checkout` Object. Then there is the appropriated [method `get_value()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#1013-1040) to be used on it...

> **What is that for?** 
> Once the customer has submitted at least one order, the selected value for "`billing_country_zone`" will be displayed on checkout page.

So you will have to replace the line:

```
), WC()->customer->billing_country_zone );
```

by this one:

```
), $checkout->get_value('billing_country_zone') );
```

> If `$checkout` variable argument is not defined, you will use `WC()->checkout` like:
>
> ```
> ), WC()->checkout->get_value('billing_country_zone') );
> ```

---

Now when you will save this custom checkout field value, you will need to save it:

1. As order meta data
2. And also **as User meta data**

So Here is the complete code *(commented)*:

```
// Display custom checkout field
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'display_custom_checkout_field' );
function display_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    $options = array_merge( [ '' => __( 'Nothing to select' ), ], city_zone() );
    woocommerce_form_field( 'billing_country_zone', array(
            'type'     => 'select',
            'class'    => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
            'label'    => __( 'City zone' ),
            'required' => true,
            'options'  => $options
    ), $checkout->get_value('billing_country_zone') );
}

// custom checkout field validation
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_checkout_field_validation' );
function custom_checkout_field_validation() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_country_zone'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_country_zone'] ) )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please select a <strong>"City zone"</strong>.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
}

// Save custom checkout field value as custom order meta data and user meta data too
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 20, 2 );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order, $data ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_country_zone'] ) ) {
        // Save custom checkout field value
        $order->update_meta_data( '_billing_country_zone', esc_attr( $_POST['billing_country_zone'] ) );

        // Save the custom checkout field value as user meta data
        if( $order->get_customer_id() )
            update_user_meta( $order->get_customer_id(), 'billing_country_zone', esc_attr( $_POST['billing_country_zone'] ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

Comment: thank you so much it worked .. if i need to send that field value to my customized function that calculate rate between shipper zone and destination zone is that okay to do that $checkout=new WC_Checkout(); $zone = $checkout->get_value('billing_country_zone'); and send $zone value ? or i can get the field value from function or something else in wordpress ?

Comment: @RowanMamdouh Welcome … As explained this value only exist if customer has already purchased something before. So you can get this value **(testing if it exist)** from user data using `get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_country_zone', true );` … *Or in backend from an existing `$order` Object use  `$order->get_meta( '_billing_country_zone' );`*